# window.innerHeight issue on android 2.3.5

Tags: javascript, android

First off: Yes I did google, I even got into the dark-side of the google search results.

Using an Android Nexus S and the default browsers on Android 2.3.5 window.innerHeight reports the wrong value.

It reports the value of the window.height (which should be 452) minus the keyboard height (207). This specifically happens after a reload (touching the addressbar and clicking 'go').

This example code returns the wrong results:

```
$(function() {
    alert(window.innerHeight); // 245

    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(window.innerHeight); // 245
    }, 1000);
});
```

The following all return wrong results:

```
$(body).height(); // (way) too high
screen.height; // 245
window.outerHeight; // 600+
document.body.offsetHeight; //646
screen.height / window.devicePixelRatio - window.screenTop; //125.xxx;
```

The window.onResize event does not trigger, However, rotating it twice does fix the height issue (but I can't tell my clients to do that).

I messed around a bit with the viewport. This is my current one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no target-densityDpi=160" />
```

I'm hoping that I missed a niche corner off the internet where the holy grail of android and window.innerHeight is available (and free to use ;)

So if you know of any solution, or anything that fixed something similar in the past, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the exact same issue as you, and the fix is exactly the same -- rotating twice.

Other than that -- wait for a different Android version.